# Debugging Excel macro called from Access macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I use Access to make Excel reports by automating Excel, using a macro enabeled template Excel file (xltm).
After having put data into Excel cells, I start an Excel macro from Access VBA code:

```
appExcel.Run ("ExcelMacro()")
```

I can run the macro, but it does not do exactly the same as when run directly within Excel. I have set a breakpoint in the Excel code to see what really happens, but the execution does not stop at the breakpoint when called from Access.

Is there a way to step execution into the Excel VBA code from Access?

Comment: For one, don't add parentheses to `Application.Run`. That tends to cause a lot of weirdness. But there's no way to debug afaik. You can try modifying the macro to add a `Stop` to manually break, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Why not import the excel macro code into access and run everything from Access? VBA doesn't care which host is running the code, as long as your explicit about which app you are controlling.

Comment: You could add some illegal instruction at the beginning of the excel macro so it will break upon execution, then step it further through the debugger.

Comment: My mind first goes to the question "are fully qualified object references used in the Excel macro?"

Comment: Welcome to SO. *it does not do exactly the same as when run directly within Excel* This is too broad. I'm afraid you need to be more explicit. What is not working properly? What does the macro do? What is supossed to do? Not enough info.